# VBA in Excel - how to get a cell value if only condition is true in loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

[image]

how to get the only name which is colum B in cloum E when the status is > 0 in Excel VBA,
please help out.

Comment: Take a look at the Advanced Filter functionality of Excel! Or if you do it in VBA, use the following approach: apply AutoFilter to A:C, filter C for >0, copy all visible cell (`Range.SpecialCells(...)` - and paste it in E2.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i know it is the quite simple like =if(c2>0,b2,"" after that index the colum and remove the blank, but i don't want the blank value, if have any other thinks in VBA if function within loop?

Comment: did you read my comment at all? have you checked the autofilter or the advanced filter?

Comment: yes i read, actually i have two different worksheet, and i want to copy the required colum B data in another worksheet bases on the status which is >0

Comment: well, then use it Filters! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple Example and should be expanded to fit you needs

```
Sub CopyName() 
    Dim lcell AS Range
    For Each lcell in Range("$B$2","$B$15")
        If Cells(lcell.Row,lcell.Column + 1) > 0 Then
           Cells(lcell.Row,"E").Value = lcell.Value
        End If
    Next lcell 
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, when its possible to copy only > 0 rather then blank?

Comment: Blank will be ignored as it is not greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

In Column E, you can paste the following:

`=IF(B1>0, A1, "")`

If column B has a value greater than 0, it will fill in column A's value. Otherwise, it'll fill in an empty string (i.e. nothing).

Comment: The OP explicitly mentioned that "i don't want the blank value" (in a comment).